# How to read data from excel file and create a graph using java or groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jfreechart, xssf, hssfworkbook

i'm trying to read data from excel and plot graph using java.

I keep getting the below error:

> org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/util/PublicCloneable

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.jfree.data.*;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

    public class ReadExcel{
        public static void main(String[]args){
    short a=0;  
    short b=1;  
     int i=0;   
    ArrayList<Integer> list1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int   x=0, y=0;  
       String filename ="C:\\Chart.xlsx";     
        if(filename != null && !filename.equals("")){
        try{    
        FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);    
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);   
        for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){    
         int j=i+1;    
         HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);    
         int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();    
         for(int r =     1; r < rows; r++){    
         HSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);    
         int cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();    
            HSSFCell cell1  = row.getCell(a);      
            x =(int) cell1.getNumericCellValue();    
            HSSFCell cell2  = row.getCell(b);     
            y =(int) cell2.getNumericCellValue();     

            list1.add(new Integer(x));
            list2.add(new Integer(y));   
          }       
          i++;   
        }    
}catch(Exception e){ 
    System.out.println(e);

 }

 }
 DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
  for(int j=0;j<list1.size();j++){
        dataset.setValue((double)list2.get(j), "Marks", list1.get(j).toString());
  }
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("BarChart using JFreeChart","ID", "Marks", dataset, 
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false,true, false);
               try {
               ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File("C:\\chart.jpg"), chart,400, 300);
               } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("Problem in creating chart.");
  }
 }
}
```

Sample excel:

```
Response Time   Transaction Name    Runid
25                    Home           1
56                    Login          2
23                    Order          3
```

i tried to use the XSSF Apache POI but no luck.

I also wanted to save the image of the chart somewhere locally.

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` means that the JVM is unable to find a class that you're using in your code. In a general way, it means you're missing a dependency in your classpath. Try adding this dependency to your project: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jcommon

Comment: I tried that as well. Keep getting same error org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)

Comment: @syndy1989, this error is clear. Apache poi has 2 different libs (HSSF 
 and XSSF) to handle excel files (xls and xlsx). If your excel version is > 2007, you should use XSSF. 

It's in the documentation: "HSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel '97(-2007) file format. XSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx) file format."

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

- commons-collections4-4.1.jar
- commons-compress-1.25.0.jar
- jcommon.jar
- xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar

Load these jar files.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.data.*;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ChartExample{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        short a=0;
        short b=1;
        int i=0;
        ArrayList<Integer> list1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list2=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int   x=0, y=0;
        String filename ="D:\\My software Development\\Trial Projects\\readxl\\src\\xytable.xls";
        if(filename != null && !filename.equals("")){
            try{
                FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
                HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
                for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
                    int j=i+1;
                    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
                    int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
                    for(int r =     1; r < rows; r++){
                        HSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);
                        int cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
                        HSSFCell cell1  = row.getCell(a);
                        x =(int) cell1.getNumericCellValue();
                        HSSFCell cell2  = row.getCell(b);
                        y =(int) cell2.getNumericCellValue();

                        list1.add(new Integer(x));
                        list2.add(new Integer(y));
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);

            }

        }
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        for(int j=0;j<list1.size();j++){
            dataset.setValue((double)list2.get(j), "Counts", list1.get(j).toString());
        }
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("BarChart using JFreeChart","Energy", "Counts", dataset,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false,true, false);
        try {
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File("D:\\My software Development\\Trial Projects\\readxl\\src\\chart.jpg"), chart,600, 600);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem in creating chart.");
        }


        /////////////////////////////
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 660 , 667 ) );
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800,800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(chartPanel);


        //////////////////////////
    }
}
```